# How to express that a gas is leaking

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Picture this: there is a gas at high pressure in a pipe. There is a hole in the pipe, and the gas is leaking from that hole at high speed.

How can I express that concisely?

I can think about: "The gas is buzzing and fuzzing, leaking from the pipe"
But does buzzing and fuzzing expresses correctly this idea?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Hissing' is the sound one would expect.

Comment: Ah makes sense. Does buzzing and fuzzing work at all, or not?

Comment: @DevShark Non-native here, but I would associate *buzzing* with something electrical (like certain door bells or some machinery) or insects. *Fuzzing* does not mean anything to me in that context.

Comment: Buzzing and fuzzing suggests the pipe is loose in a pipe clamp or other mounting bracket and in some kind of periodic reactive motion with the leak, if that is your intent - but it makes sense on the pipe, not the gas.

Answer (score 1):

"Gas leak" is the common term for the overall situation. Example: "They had to evacuate the building due to a gas leak."

As Edwin pointed out in the comment above, "hissing" is usually how you'd describe the *sound* it makes.  Or you might say "whooshing" if the opening is larger.

I'm not sure of a term that would specifically emphasize the high speed of the leak, though "high pressure gas leak" might come close.

Comment: I see. I was trying to go for something a little more visual/poetic. Does buzzing and fuzzing work at all, or is it weird? Thanks

Comment: Please avoid giving simplistic answers to questions not of ELU standard  as 'answers'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What is the "ELU standard"? Can you provide a link so I can understand what you mean? Also, what would you suggest adding to this answer to make it less "simplistic"?  It seems more complete than the other three answers below.

Comment: I don't think there can be better than a simplistic answer here. I've close-voted. ELU is aimed at linguists; I'd reckon this means not inviting answers such as 'hissing', 'screeching', 'gas leak', 'leaking from the hole in the pressurized pipe with a scary and strong whooshing sound', 'blasting' etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider saying, "The gas is leaking from the hole in the pressurized pipe with a scary and strong whooshing sound."

Comment: A sarcastic response is best expressed as a comment rather than an answer. Better yet, it may be withheld altogether.

Comment: @John Go-Soco Though I don't consider this a suitable response on a site aimed at linguists, neither do I consider it intended to be sarcastic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps it is just me then. Still, in future I shall refrain from making similar comments.

Comment: FYI, No sarcasm intended.

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced a faulty valve release hydrogen at high pressure into a small laboratory I would categorically describe the sound as '**screeching**'.

> a. **intr. To make a loud, harsh, piercing noise.**
>   1792   ‘P. Pindar’ Tears of St. Margaret 9   The fiddles screech with rapture one and all.
>   1824   W. Irving Tales of Traveller II. iv. 272   The ungreased wheels groaned and screeched on the axletrees.
>   1861   Harper's New Monthly Mag. Apr. 663/1   Just then a train screeched into the station.
>   1871   J. Hawthorne Idolatry I. ix. 136   The fog-whistle screeched dismally.
>   1905   Tales July 89/2   The whirling sand screeched by on both sides.
>   1920   H. Titus Last Straw xvi. 166   Bullets screeched overhead.
>   1992   J. R. Dominguez & V. Robin Your Money or your Life ii. 43   Cars, trucks and buses honk and belch and screech up and down the street.
>   2015   E. K. Arnold Question of Miracles 140   The teacher's chalk screeched across the board.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/173425?rskey=LvOdMk&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

No other words describes what I can remember of that sound to this day, just over forty years ago. We couldn't shut off the valve and we had to evacuate the building. Since hydrogen flashes explosively at above 4% concentration in air and there was a hotplate within reach there was a genuine risk of a really nasty outcome.

Answer (score -1):

For a bit of drama you could try:

> The gas is *blasting* out of the pipe.

Alternatively, you can use jetting or shooting.